# Magento 2 Readiness check error

Tags: error, upgrade, magento-2.1.4, component-manager

I am getting the following error on the readiness check step:

> We found conflicting component dependencies. 
>   Command "update" failed: Loading composer repositories with package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. Problem 1 - The requested package magento/product-community could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name. Potential causes: - A typo in the package name - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability for more details. Read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further common problems.

I read on the official docs that they might be a typo in composer.json file. My file is like this:

```
{
"name": "magento/project-community-edition",
"description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
"type": "project",
"version": "2.1.4",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.8",
    "composer/composer": "@alpha",
    "magento/product-community": "2.1.8"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "2.2.2",
    "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.0"
},
"config": {
    "use-include-path": true
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
        "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
        "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
    },
    "psr-0": {
        "": "app/code/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
        "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
        "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "alpha",
"prefer-stable": true,
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    }
],
"extra": {
    "magento-force": "override"
}
```

}

Can't think what's wrong. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to remove `"magento/product-community": "2.1.8"`

Answer (score 1):

Replace :

```
"require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.8",
    "composer/composer": "@alpha",
    "magento/product-community": "2.1.8"
},
```

With this :

```
"require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.8",
        "composer/composer": "@alpha"
    },
```

Hope it works

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work...When I run the test again, the file is modified and the line is rewritten back in... :/

Answer (score -1):

Remove this from composer.json

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
    "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
    "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
    "pdepend/pdepend": "2.2.2",
    "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
    "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0",
    "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.0"
},
```

Run this from SSH inside your Magento root directory:

```
php bin/magento cron:install
php bin/magento cron:run
php update/cron.php
php bin/magento setup:cron:run
```

Or edit this script:

```
Magento/Setup/Controller/Environment.php
```

```
//$setupCheck = $this->cronScriptReadinessCheck->checkSetup();
//$updaterCheck = $this->cronScriptReadinessCheck->checkUpdater();
$setupCheck = ['success' => 1];
$updaterCheck = ['success' => 1];
```

https://ostap.dev/readiness-check-failure-magento-2/